# Get Information About Inavlidated HttpServletRequest Session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications, tomcat7

I want to differentiate between:

1. New session created by time-out of previous session.
2. A new session created by opening the page in new session of a browser.

Is there a way I can identify these two in a new `HTTPServeletRequest`?

Comment: What do you plan to do with this information?

Comment: Decide on the new page to be redirected to

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [`SessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and manage to get new session and old session mapping,

However to decide where to redirect upon new login (as you commented)

you should store [`referrer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header in session

For example:

- after session has been destroyed
- user gets redirected to login page
- get the referrer header put it in session and on successful login read it from session and redirect there

Comment: Referer value is missing from header once browser is refreshed after session is invalidated via session Timeout

Comment: I suppose referer can be read from request header of HttpServletRequest. Referer value is not available in the header, once the session is invalidated. This may not be true for a page reload in some webkit browsers. But I guess this property cannot be relied upon.

Comment: referrer is not dependent on session, please put the request sequence and provide more detail where you loose this header